# Which Flutter version is safe for Production Release?

Tags: flutter

I'm currently on `version 3.3.9 channel stable` and experiencing some weird assertion error from 'text_painter.dart:975:12' - which is the following function:

```
 /// Returns the position within the text for the given pixel offset.
  TextPosition getPositionForOffset(Offset offset) {
    assert(!_debugNeedsLayout);
    return _paragraph!.getPositionForOffset(offset);
  }
```

I'm working on web and it seems to happen when I move my cursor over the screen before the page has fully loaded - before my custom fonts show up.

Has anyone else experienced something similar? What's my safest option for a production release?

** UPDATE

Now using latest version `3.3.10 channel stable` and still facing the same issue. Additionally, found this comment the source code:

```
// The TextPainter class should not aggressively invalidate the layout as long
// as `markNeedsLayout` is not called (i.e., the layout cache is still valid).
// See: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85108
```

Comment: it means that you have not called `layout` method

Comment: Thank you @pskink

Where and when would one call `layout` method?

Comment: before calling `getPositionForOffset`

Comment: Are you using Textpainter or getting error in the source code?

Comment: Not using TextPainter at all - error is from source code @Prashant

Comment: Ok. I am posting solution as a answer

Answer (score 1):

Try updating Flutter Source packages:
To update to the latest compatible versions of all the dependencies listed in the pubspec.yaml file, use the upgrade command:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

If still issue persists,
Try updating all packages:

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Comment: unfortunately changed nothing

Answer (score 1):

This must be a source code error from flutter. You should try downgrading to version 3.2.0. I find It more state in production rollouts.

Comment: I'll try look into it a bit more and use this as a last resort, thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Any new information you find out, let us know here.